# Bone matrices manipulating problem

Tags: scripting, bones, transforms, matrix

So I'm trying to convert additive animations to a weird format that Source engine uses: instead of offsetting the bone relative to its local space, it uses whole armature's origin point for that. All bones that aren't used in the additive animation should be located at 0, 0, 0 and rotated 90 degrees on the Y-axis, the rest of the bones use this transform as a relative point for their animation.
Here's an example with a decompiled model from TF2:
[image]

So far I've been trying to get a single bone conversion to work and have written up a script (I don't have much experience with blender API, practical coding and linear maths in general so bare with me here :D)

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
import math


def main():
    bone = bpy.context.active_pose_bone
    obj = bpy.data.objects['rig']
    def_pos =  Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(90), 4, 'Y')
    armature = bpy.data.armatures['rig']
    
    #1. Get global coordinates of the bone in rest posistion
    armature.pose_position = "REST"
    gl_mat = bone.matrix * obj.matrix_world
    #2. Get transition matrix to the needed transform (gl_tr_mat = def_pos / gl_mat)
    gl_tr_mat = def_pos.inverted_safe() * gl_mat
    #3. Transform resulting matrix into local space (loc_tr_mat = gl_tr_mat / matrix_world)
    loc_tr_mat = obj.matrix_world.inverted_safe() * gl_tr_mat
    #4. Apply to the same bone in the pose position
    armature.pose_position = "POSE"
    bone.matrix = loc_tr_mat * bone.matrix
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The main issues are that the bone ends up scaled to 0 on all axis except for the one it's rotated on (Y here) and it doesn't face in the right direction: [image: code execution example]

What's the issue here?

Blender's version is 2.90.0, Steam build

Comment: Matrix multiplication should use '@' not '*' in Python 3.5. Try to replace them all four, should be fine, I think.

Comment: @lemon the scaling is consistent now (more or less), but other transforms are wrong. The bone from the example now is set to -6 -5.1 -2,89 (xyz) on location and 0.385 -0.608 0.692, -0.057 (wxyz) on rotation